# Subquery with more than one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I try to build a subquery with more than one column. Like this:

```
--SELF JOIN:
WITH Employees AS
(
    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID, e.Title,
        c.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + c.MiddleName,'') + ' ' + c.LastName AS EmpName
    FROM 
        Employee AS e
    INNER JOIN 
        Contact AS c ON e.ContactID = c.ContactID
)
SELECT 
    emp.EmployeeID, emp.ManagerID, emp.EmpName, emp.Title AS EmpTitle,
    mgr.EmpName as MgrName, mgr.Title as MgrTitle
FROM 
    Employees AS Emp 
INNER JOIN 
    Employees AS Mgr ON Emp.ManagerID = Mgr.EmployeeID;

--2
WITH Employees AS 
(
    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID, e.Title,
        c.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + c.MiddleName,'') + ' ' + c.LastName AS EmpName
    FROM 
        Employee AS e
    INNER JOIN 
        Contact AS c ON e.ContactID = c.ContactID
)
SELECT 
    EmployeeID, ManagerID, EmpName, Title
FROM 
    Employees
WHERE 
    EmployeeID IN  (SELECT EmployeeID, er2.MaritalStatus
                    FROM Employees AS e
                    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee AS er2 ON e.ManagerID = er2.BusinessEntityID
                    WHERE er2.MaritalStatus = 'M');
```

I want also to show the `MarialStatus`. But I can't do it this way, because I get the error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

But If I can't do it with exists in the subquery. So my question is: what is the proper way that I can select more then one column in the subquery?

Thank you

Comment: Why would someone use `tempdb` for physical tables

Comment: @Prdp looks like the OP is experimenting with AdventureWorks data.

Comment: the OP? what do you mean with OP??

Comment: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return 2 values in a sub query.So you will have to remove the  `MaritalStatus` column.  That's the problem with your query.

```
USE tempdb;
WITH
Employees AS(
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID,e.Title,
c.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + c.MiddleName,'') + ' ' + c.LastName AS EmpName
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Contact AS c
ON e.ContactID = c.ContactID
)
SELECT emp.EmployeeID, emp.ManagerID, emp.EmpName, emp.Title AS EmpTitle,
mgr.EmpName as MgrName, mgr.Title as MgrTitle
FROM Employees AS Emp INNER JOIN Employees AS Mgr
ON Emp.ManagerID = Mgr.EmployeeID;
--2
WITH Employees AS (
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID,e.Title,
c.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + c.MiddleName,'') + ' ' + c.LastName AS EmpName
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Contact AS c
ON e.ContactID = c.ContactID)

SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID, e.EmpName, e.Title,er2.MaritalStatus
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee AS er2 
ON e.ManagerID = er2.BusinessEntityID
WHERE er2.MaritalStatus = 'M');
```

I don't think you need a subquery there,because `INNER JOIN` will give you only records if there's a match. So do a `INNER JOIN` fro the table and put the `MaritalStatus` column in the select clause

Comment: Ah, Thank you. Very nice

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in your second query.  The second column is not necessary in the `SELECT`.  But, you can further simplify the logic by removing the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID, e.EmpName, e.Title
FROM Employees e
WHERE e.ManagerID IN (SELECT er2.BusinessEntityID
                      FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee er2
                      WHERE er2.MaritalStatus = 'M'
                     );
```